# How do I keep a rigidbody from making unnecessary collisions on smooth surfaces in Unity3d?

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection, physics, collision-avoidance

I have been having trouble with a custom character controller I am making. The root of the problem lies with collisions. I am trying to make movement code, but I have a problem with ground movement. Pay attention to [this](https://i.gyazo.com/1204347ae2710d21c207c25157899ef5.gif) gif. It might be hard to notice due to the low frame rate, but *the collider registers collisions with objects (in red) that do not point out of the ground*. They share the same y-position as the ground. I've printed the normals of the collisions, and there are a lot of normals that are perpendicular to the normal of the ground (which is causing the rigidbody to get stuck).

The problem lies with collisions in unity. If I were to print the y-position of the bottom of my collider, it would be just a tad lower than the y-position of the ground. The collider actually rests below the ground by an almost negligible amount (which is why it doesn't always collide with these objects).

**Here is what I have tried:** I created a function that runs at the beginning of every FixedUpdate() that uses current collisions to change the y-position of the rigidbody. It only runs on collisions that *would* ground the player (meaning that they are below the collider). The problem with this approach is that the same issue can occur with walls, meaning that the collider can get stuck on walls. I cannot create another function that would do the same for walls for various reasons.

**Here is what would fix the issue:** I need help figuring out how I can make collisions more discrete in unity. Colliders rest slightly below objects when ontop of them. They can also "sink" just a little into walls. In other words, colliders can rest into other colliders, and I need this to stop.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to game physics engines. [Bennett Foddy goes into some detail about why physics engines work like this and what you can do about it in this GDC session](https://youtu.be/NwPIoVW65pE)

Comment: Have you tried making your collision continuous on your block? Discrete collisions resolve AFTER the fact by applying forces. This is why it's slightly below. Continuous collisions will only simulate to the point of collision, and apply the resolution forces there. It might resolve your issue at the cost of some performance. Although modern continuous collision is very performant albeit not as much as discrete.

Comment: @gjh33 Yes I have. It does not solve the problem.

Comment: Why does character stop sometimes when entering the red zone? Is red zone supposed to register those collisions? What is a purpose of a red zone?

Comment: You're unlikely to be able to change the way the physics engine detects & handles contacts. So let's instead focus on the problem it causes for your game: why do you have these nearly-coincident surfaces in the first place? To reduce distractions for the physics engine, could we set the red object as a trigger or separate it onto a non-colliding physics layer, and check for overlaps with the red region in a different way? The more you can tell us about what this red patch is supposed to *do*, the better we can help you achieve those goals.

Comment: @CandidMoon_Max_ The red zone doesn't signify anything. Imagine I had two surfaces and wanted to connect them; by putting them next to each other, the player collider would register a collision when crossing from one platform to the other. Essentially, this problem doesn't occur because objects are inside each other. I made the question that way so it could be easier to understand. If there are two objects that are *touching* and that share the same y-position, the collider will still experience this issue.

Comment: I got the general idea. But I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve, the end result. "the collider registers collisions with objects (in red) that do not point out of the ground" - from this I got that even red collider is on the same y level as ground raycasts do not register collisions with ground but instead with the red patch?